# Bluetooth mouse not functioning

Tags: usb, mouse, bluetooth, usbhid

So I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I have a generic brand mouse and a generic brand USB bluetooth module. my issue is that I can't quite use the mouse. I can connect but nothing happens. The two devices are connected, but the mouse itself does nothing. any idea as to why it is doing that? I am still relatively new to this.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please read [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and provide information needed to identify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the bluetooth mouse driver provided by the manufacturer, or you could check for some updates in Ubuntu update manager.

You could also check extra drivers in system preferences (is this correct?).